# problems with phrase matching in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform Phrase matching using elasticsearch.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
data - 1: {
    "test" {
       "title" : "text1 text2"
    }
}

2: {
    "test" {
       "title" : "text3 text4"
    }
}

3: {
    "test" {
       "title" : "text5"
    }
}


4: {
    "test" {
       "title" : "text6"
    }
}
```

#### Search terms:

If I lookup for "text0 text1 text2 text3" - It should return #1 (matches full string)

If I lookup for "text6 text5 text4 text3" - It should return #4, #3, but not #2 as its not in same order.

#### Here is what I've tried:

- set the `index_analyzer` as keyword, and `search_analyzer` as standard
- also tried creating custom tokens

but none of my solution allows me to lookup a substring match from search query against keyword in document.

If anyone has written similar queries, can you provide how the mappings are configured and what kind of query is been used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see here is this: You want your search to match on any tokens sent from the query. If those tokens do match, it must be an exact match to the title.

This means that indexing your title field as keyword would get you that mandatory match. However, the standard analyzer for search would never match titles spaces as you'd have your index token `{"text1 text2"}` and your search token `[{"text1},{"text2"}]`. You can't use a phrase match with any sloppy value or else your token order requirement will be ignored.

So, what you really need is to generate keyword tokens during the index, but you need to generate shingles whenever you search. Your shingles will maintain order and if one of them matches, consider it a go. I would set to not output unigrams, but do allow unigrams if no shingles. This means that if you have just one word, it will output that token, but it if can combine your search words into various number of shingled tokens, it will not emit single word tokens.

```
PUT
  { "settings":
    {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "my_shingle": {
                    "type": "shingle",
                    "max_shingle_size": 50,
                    "output_unigrams": false
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "my_shingler": {
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "my_shingle"
                    ],
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Then you just want to set your type mapping to use the keyword analyzer for index and the `my_shingler` analyzer for search.
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html

Comment: Hi J.T. can you expand on this, I am new to ES, and cant create an index with the above. And what I have created I cant query with the shingle token filter. Any chance you could spell it out for us noobs?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, how would I go about "set your type mapping to use the keyword analyzer for index and the "my_shingler" analyzer for search."

Comment: For anyone having the same doubt, the new _definitive guide_ has quite a good section on this
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/proximity-matching.html